# java arrayoutofbound exception after compiling

Tags: java

```
package binarywa;
import java.util.*;

public class binaryadd {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
        String g=scan.next();
        String s[]=g.split("");
        int i,x=0;


        for(i=s.length;i>0;i--)
        {

         x+=Integer.parseInt(s[i])*Math.pow(2,i);
         }  

    }

}
```

Im trying to convert binary into decimal

but after compiling this im getting an arrayoutofbound exception

eg:
541656(its the input)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6
    at binarywa.binaryadd.main(binaryadd.java:16)

Comment: `s.length` will always be outside the array. If `s = [1,2,3]`, `s.length = 3`, but `s[3]` doesnt exist.

Comment: `i=s.length - 1`

Comment: @ScaryWombat i tried s.length-1 but then its not printing 1st digit

Comment: use `for(i = s.length - 1; i > -1; i --)`

Comment: @AbhishekVishwakarma use this in your for loop. `for(i=s.length-1;i>=0;i--)`
It will print all elements. See my answer for explanation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

keep the length s.length-1 and i>=0 will print the first element 
as array index start from 0

```
package binarywa;
import java.util.*;

public class binaryadd {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
        String g=scan.next();
        String s[]=g.split("");
        int i,x=0;


        for(i=s.length-1;i>=0;i--)
        {

         x+=Integer.parseInt(s[i])*Math.pow(2,i);
         }  

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

the for loop conditions are incorrect. Array indices are accessible from `0` to `(length - 1)`. This is the reason you are getting `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`

```
for (i = s.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
```

Answer (score 0):

`s.length` in your code snipped will return 4.

In the loop you are trying to access `s[4]` which doesn't have a value.
The `s[]` formed by `g.split("")` will have `{1,2,3,4}`

The indexes of these 4 array elements start with 0.

so,

```
s[0]=1
s[1]=2
s[2]=3
s[3]=4
```

once you try to access `s[4]` it will give ArrayIndexOutofBoundsException since at that index you don't have any value.

Solution is to run the loop as `for(i=s.length-1;i>=0;i--)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the for loop to as per the below

```
package binarywa;
import java.util.*;

public class binaryadd {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner scan=new Scanner(System.in);
        String g=scan.next();
        String s[]=g.split("");
        int i,x=0;


        for(i=s.length-1;i>=0;i--)
        {

         x+=Integer.parseInt(s[i])*Math.pow(2,i);
         }  

    }

}
```

But for that you also need to change your logic. i.e.

```
 x+=Integer.parseInt(s[i])*Math.pow(2,i+1);
```

else it will throw the NumberFormat Exception.